# Checking for status of jquery hide and show

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function:

```
expandContact = () => {
    $('#' + this.props.id).find('.ekipa-li-expand').show();
  }
```

Now I would like to write a condition that checks if the element is visible or not (I would like to hide the element on click if it's shown, and show it if it's hidedn.

Far as I can tell the `.show()` function just adds `style="display: block;"` to the DOM element. But how do I check for this in a condition with javascript?

Comment: You could use .toggle() instead of .show()

Comment: As said in the comments, you can use `toggle` to switch the state. But if you want to know if a element is visible, use `is(":visible")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write any condition, you can just use `toggle()`:

```
expandContact = () => {
  $('#' + this.props.id).find('.ekipa-li-expand').toggle();
}
```

For reference, if, for whatever reason, you did need to know the visible state of an element you can use the `is()` method with the `:visible` selector:

```
if ($('#' + this.props.id).find('.ekipa-li-expand').is(':visible')) {
  // do something...
}
```